# pip inside virtual environment is pointing to global installation and doesnt use the virtualenv site packages

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, python-3.5

I have a local repo where I have installed packages like django, django rest framework with virtual environment, I have pushed it to git and when I have downloaded the repo on a remote server, I have activated the virtualenv using `source bin/activate` and tried to run django server, it is showing the packages which are installed inside the virtualenv as not installed

I have tried to use

```
which python3.5
```

It gives me `/usr/bin/python3.5`
And which pip3 gives `/usr/local/bin/pip3`, what do I need to make the virtualenv to use the packages inside virtual env lib/ folder? I have no aliases set on bashrc, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: When you activate your venv does the prompt change? Can you try running `which python`?

Comment: @lain Shelvington it gives me /usr/bin/python

Comment: I work on Linux so this may not work for you but shouldn't you be run `source venv/bin/activate` in order to activate your virtualenv?  Having done that does you command line prompt change to show the virtualenv name?  If not, you're not in the virtualenv

Comment: yes it does show the venv name @HenryM